# Getting arbitraty results every time while running a SQL server procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, timeout

We are using SQL server 2016. The application which is using a specific search procedure is returning data sometimes and sometimes this is throwing "Timeout error". There is no deadlock happened and we cannot apply trace in production. This is also not happening in any other environment. This is something wired as there is no pattern for throwing error. Even when the application is throwing "Timeout error" then EXECUTing stored procedure is running in pretty less time. This is a burning issue in production for quite a long time. 
Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned deadlock - perhaps you mean blocking? You will not get a timeout if the procedure is actually executing within the client-specified command timeout. I suggest you focus on optimized the problem search proc. See [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: Hmm, not much to go on right now. I'd like to know how much data is supposed to be returned when the timeout occurs; if you debug this using the same input parameters on a copy of the production database, what happens? Is this a command timeout or connection timeout? You say this is happening only in production, can you tell something about your infrastructure and if there are any differences between UAT and production?

Comment: Have you checked SQLServer Error Logs to see what exactly the cause of the timeout? or tried `SP_who2` while facing such issue to see any query in suspended mode?

Comment: @Dan Thanks all for your valuable comments and time. This SP is written without dynamic SQL to boost up the performance.

Comment: Thailo, with No params, its returning 1500 records and with param, its returning 7-15 records. But sometimes both are returning and sometimes not. THis is a connect timeout. And not happenign in UAT. Sathiya Kumar error log or SP_Who2 is showing no error.

Comment: There is no definitive answer as to whether static or dynamic SQL will provide the best performance for your dynamic search conditions. With static SQL, an option recompile query hint often provides a better plan but one must consider the compilation costs when the query is executed frequently.

Comment: You just mentioned connection timeout rather than command timeout. Intermittent connection timeouts suggests an infrastructure problem.

Comment: Thanks Dan...could you please help more on infrastructure problem? May be that is  an issue.